# Unity KeyCode for mute button for Fire TV remote

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this problem when I'm looking at the amazon developer page for unity: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/controller-input-with-unity.html#controller-names

it shows the keycodes for all the buttons, except for the mute button on the remote.
My model is different; there's a volume button and a mute button. Neither of these are documented.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Those instructions are for the Old "Input Manager" if you wish to support, the "Rewind, Play/Pause, And FastForward Buttons" you must override the Android Main Activity, to remap this buttons.
Another Solution could be using Input System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer but you could maybe try to simply print it out using something like

```csharp
public class Debug : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Just print to a text so you can easily see the result on the screen 
    public Text text;

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        var e = Event.current;

        if (e.keyCode != KeyCode.None)
        {
            text.text = e.keyCode.ToString();
        }
    }   
}
```

this way you could see which keycode responds to which pressed button/key etc.

Comment: That's great! One problem tho... when I build for the tv rn I get a message about it not being meant for this hardware and I get pink chaos lol. Thanks for the code though, it's really useful! :)

Comment: @Thunder hmm that's sounds like a general issue with your project then ^^ I doubt that this code would cause this, right? Except for some reason the `OnGUI` itself causes issues but it would be the first time I hear of that

Comment: No, I meant that I can’t use ur code because of the pink chaos. Sorry for the misunderstanding. 

Comment: The pink screen sounds like your Fire TV stick is a model that only supports OpenGL 2.0
Your log file should also report an incompatible OpenGL API version.

You can check this list to see OpenGL versions available to each model:
https://www.brutalhack.com/blog/fire-tv-hardware-overview/#OpenGL_ES_Support

Answer (score 0):

According to the Fire TV Guidelines, volume +/- and mute are not to be mapped.

I heard that it's possible, but you will get rejected from the amazon appstore.

Source: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/remote-input.html

If you use the new input system, I released an asset on the assetstore which gives you access to all mappable buttons (Dpad, Select, Back, Menu, Rewind, Play/Pause, FastForward)
I'm not posting any links, but it's easy to find if you search for "Fire TV" on the asset store.